# Flask with css doesnt seem to be working properly

Tags: html, css, flask

Sorry if this is a little vague. I have been attempting to use build a simple table. I have been following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mCy52I4exTU), though when I run the site, the css doesnt seem to work. some parts do, for example the row colouring, but nothing else. Rather odd, hopefully one of you can help me out.

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Mankey Activity</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styles.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="table">
      <tr class="table__header">
        {% for header in headings %}
        <th class="table__cell>">{{ header }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
      {% for row in data %}
      <tr class="table__row">
        {% for cell in row %}
        <td class="table__cell">{{ cell }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-radius: 4;
  margin: 1rem;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.table__row:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.table__header {
  text-align: left;
}


.table__cell {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Site:

[image: Site]

Sorry if i am being stupid.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styles.css"/>` with this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}">`

Comment: Should have mentioned I tried that. Double checked since you commented it, still doesnt work. same result.

Comment: can you share your project structure

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/8Fo4HXo

Comment: Check if there is a 404 error in the server logs, something like styles.css not found, 404 error. If there is a 404 error then the app is not able to find your CSS file.
ELSE
Clear the cache, or do a hard refresh (right-click on the reload button on google chrome and choose hard reload)

Comment: But it can find the css, as it is using ".table__row:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}", just nothing else. I have tried all of that. No difference. Sorry, i am new to this.

Comment: My bad, im being stupid. needed to clear cache (twice, for some reason). Sorry!